"unknown command ^" in bat file when calling WinSCP with wrapped lines
I am trying to download a file using WinSCP from a .bat file.  I have the connection working now, but it keeps erroring out with the unknown command ^.
Any ideas how to resolve this?
Here is my code:
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
/log="C:\temp\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
/command ^
"open sftp://un:pw@sftp.site.com/ -hostkey=""*"" -privatekey=""C:\Location\To\Private.ppk""" ^
"cd /" ^
"lcd C:\temp\LatestFile" ^
"get -latest Filename*" ^
"exit"


I'm not getting the error you mentioned with your batch file. In any case, your batch file has wrong syntax. The continuation lines should be indented:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
    /log="C:\temp\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
    /command ^
    "open sftp://un:pw@sftp.site.com/ -hostkey=""*"" -privatekey=""C:\Location\To\Private.ppk""" ^
    "cd /" ^
    "lcd C:\temp\LatestFile" ^
    "get -latest Filename*" ^
    "exit"

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file#newline_escaping

Thank you.  It was the indentation that was wrong.  I feel rather stupid, as I only took that out for editing, and just had forgotten that the indents are required.
